# Trying to declare multiple characteristics for an object through for loop

Tags: javascript, object

Hey so I started to pick up Javascript and I'm having a little bit of trouble with objects. 
I'm trying to create a shape class that takes in a number of sides. Using these sides, it creates more characteristics so it can store the co-ordinates of the location of a point. 
What I have right now is a class that is taking in the size, and I want to use a for loop to create the "properties" in which to store the positions. Just for learning purposes I'm setting them to 0, to see if it's even possible to do this. Any clarification on objects would be appreciated.

```
function Shape(size) {
    this.size = size
    for(var i=0; i<size; i++){ //tries to create the properties
        //this[i].posX: 0;
        //this[i].posY = 0;
    }
}
```

Ideally, I want to access them so it's in this type of format:

```
var triangle = new Shape(3);
triangle[0].posX = 100; // So essentially I could set this to 100, the integer in the [] would represent a side.
triangle[0].posY = 100; // etc ... for the rest of the sides
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the shape can have a variable number of sides, I would recommend creating an ***Array*** of points as a property of the Shape class.

```
function Shape(size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.point = new Array();//stores an Array of Points
    for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
        this.point[i] = new Point(0, 0);
    }
}

function Point(x, y){
    this.posX = x || 0;
    this.posY = y || 0;
};
```

This way you can create a triangle with the following code:

```
// Creates a triangle with the points at (100, 100), (0, 0), and (0, 0)
var triangle = new Shape(3);
triangle.point[0].posX = 100;
triangle.point[0].posY = 100;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yea I ended up thinking about arrays however I felt like there might of been an easier way then creating an array of a new object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty understanding your question / what the problem is. But in my opinion, Javascript doesn't really support 'Properties' in a way like C# or VB.NET or similar languages do. Your solution is using Methods in two formats:
1. Methods that set a value.
2. Methods that return a value.
So your class should have something like these 4 methods:

```
setPosX(var posx)
getPosX()
setPosY(var posy)
getPosY()
```

Then you simply create an array:

```
var triangles = new Array();
```

And give your values through the for loop:

```
function Shape(size) {
        for(var i=0; i<size; i++){ //tries to create the properties
            triangles[i].setPosX(0); // or any other value
            triangles[i].setPosY(0);
        }
    }
```

Also notice that this function would be outside of the class structure.
Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code. Is that what you want?

```
function Shape(size) {
    var arr = new Array(size);

    for(var i=0; i <size; i++){ //tries to create the properties
        arr[i] = {
             posX: 0,
             posY: 0
        };
        //arr[i] = {};
        //arr[i].posX = 0;
        //arr[i].posY = 0;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var triangle = new Shape(3);
triangle[0].posX = 100; // So essentially I could set this to 100, the integer in the [] would represent a side.
triangle[0].posY = 100; // etc ... for the rest of the sides
```